# Insert two line breaks inbetween merged files using PASTE

Tags: bash, paste

I'm using the following command to merge several files: `paste -d"\n \n" -s *.md > big-markdown-file.md`.

My issue is that there is only one line break between the merged files:

```
# This is the start of 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te eos solet copiosae deterruisset, mea eu augue postulant temporibus. Sit ex definiebas referrentur. This is the end of file1.
# This is the start of File2.md
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te eos solet copiosae deterruisset, mea eu augue postulant temporibus. Sit ex definiebas referrentur. This is the end of file2.
# This is the start of File3.md
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te eos solet copiosae deterruisset, mea eu augue postulant temporibus. Sit ex definiebas referrentur. This is the end of file3.
```

This causes issues when the markdown is processed, turning the *lorem ipsum* paragraphs into headings. Is there a way to introduce 2 line breaks between the individual pastes in the final file so that it outputs something like this:

```
# This is the start of 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te eos solet copiosae deterruisset, mea eu augue postulant temporibus. Sit ex definiebas referrentur. This is the end of file1.

# This is the start of File2.md
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te eos solet copiosae deterruisset, mea eu augue postulant temporibus. Sit ex definiebas referrentur. This is the end of file2.

# This is the start of File3.md
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te eos solet copiosae deterruisset, mea eu augue postulant temporibus. Sit ex definiebas referrentur. This is the end of file3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe "cheat" and create a dummy file?

```
$ touch dummy
$ paste -d"\n" -s *.md dummy > big-markdown-file.md
$ rm dummy # :)
```

I think it will cause `paste` to try and consume the next line from the empty file, "fail", and create an empty line instead.

Actually, for a list of file you'll have to create a dummy for each:

```
$ # create dummy files
$ for f in *.md; do echo $f; touch ${f}_dummy.md; done
$ # create the result files
$ paste -d"\n" -s *.md > big-markdown-file.md
$ # remove dummy files
$ find -name '*dummy.md' -delete
```

Comment: It's a creative idea, but it didn't seem to work unfortunately. I also tried having several new lines within the dummy file but that didn't seem to work either. I think I may just have to cheat and enter a new line at the end of each `.md` file.

Comment: @mohnjatthews did you try the **second** part (starting from `"Actually, ..."`) of the answer? I've updated it because I've read the question wrong initially (you want to separate ALL lines, not just group the similarly indexed lines).

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! It's a bit hacky but it gets the job done :)

Comment: There must be a better way but I use what I know :)